# Real Time Communication With PHP Server and Android Application

Tags: android, webrtc, publish-subscribe, pubnub, pusher

In my project I have to send user's location periodically (E.g. 30Sec) to server using Android application and the PHP server returns nearest users and app displays them on the map. I am looking for a publish subscribe protocol for the real time data transfer.

Here is the architecture I was planned. Each mobile app users id will be considered as a topic or channel so that we can send one to one message. PHP server will considered as a topic e.g. "APP_SERVER_TRACKER". All mobile apps publishes location to Server topic. Server prepares the list and publish response to individual user's by using their id as topics.

I checked Pusher API and I would like to know how my PHP server will get user's location. Is it possible to subscribe all channels at server?

Pusher can handle higher number of users by scaling, but all user's are connecting to my PHP Server through a single channel and the server then publishing response to end user. In this scenario do I need to scale my PHP Server? Is Pusher is good choice in this scenario? Please advice?

The application will target at least 10 Million users. should support half of concurrent users.
PHP Server Hosting will be in AWS EC2 m3.2xlarge 8 core instance

Comment: Have you looked into pubnub? they can do most of the location abstraction https://www.pubnub.com/solutions/dispatch-and-logistics-tracking/

Comment: Yes I checked Pubnub also. Still confused regarding the server load, as all my app instances are publishing to my server (AWS) through a single subscribed channel, is it give any advantage in performance?

Comment: you should check pubnub and for the server side language php is not ideal. i prefer to use node.js and redis or memcachced to handle your app sessions , locations. (Redis got build in features ffor handle geo based processing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PubNub integration with PHP Server and Android Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497355/pubnub-integration-with-php-server-and-android-application)

Comment: This appears to be duplicate of your question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497355/pubnub-integration-with-php-server-and-android-application where I answered that you do not need to use your server to do what you want to do - as far as I understand your requirements. Subscribing from server side is not trivial (and not recommended with PHP - listen to @Vigikaran and opt for another language like Node, Java, Go or Python or many other choices) and unless absolutely necessary, you should opt for more *easy to scale on your server* strategies.